# Redirect users to a subdomain with new using cpanel and keep original URL on user's browser

Tags: php, drupal, cpanel

I have a php account with my provider, and I also have cpanel installed for me.

I currently have two drupal sites there, let's called the main myMainSite and another one under construction called myNewSite.

So when I go to **www.myMainSite.com**, I go to the main site. When I go to **myNewSite.myMainSite.com**, i go to the drupal site that is under construction.

My question is, when my under construction site goes live, I want that all users that go to **www.myMainSite.com** see the new site (the one that is under **myNewSite.myMainSite.com**).

How can I accomplish this with cpanel? is it within the "addon domains" configuration?
I don't want a redirect that changes the address bar, ie, I want to keep the original url.

Comment: When you say go to, do you want to redirect all requests: so I type www.myMainSite.com and my browser ends up at myNewSite.. or do you want the content from myNewSite.. to show up at www..?

Comment: I want the content to show up at www...

Answer (score 0):

You would just change the DocumentRoot of www.mainsite.com to point to the same DocumentRoot as myNewSite.myMainSite.com.

Comment: I do not control the Apache config

Answer (score 0):

I assume you've used cPanel's subdomain control panel to add **myNewSite.myMainSite.com**. And I'll assume **myMainSite.com** is in the `/public_html/` folder. Therefore the new site (and site with a subdomain) will be at `/public_html/myNewSite.myMainSite.com`

Why can't you just use File Manager (or FTP) to move all the files in `/public_html/` to `/public_html/OLDsite`?

Then move everything from `/public_html/myNewSite.myMainSite` into the `/public_html/` folder.

Then check your site is working with the new files.

Maybe you could also send a support ticket to your host to see if there's another way. It could be as simple as them changing something in Apache's conf file for the **myNewSite.myMainSite.com** subdomain.

I'd also think you'd need to change the settings in Drupal (when you've changed domain) so Drupal knows the new domain name too.

Comment: I'm using a CMS that references the full path for some directories, so I cannot move things around.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to have main 2 user accounts call  oldlive and newlive.

you may have domain like

oldlive.myMainSite.com and newlive.myMainSite.com

Then you can add Park Domain myMainSite.com to oldlive.myMainSite.com when you not ready.

Once you are completed new site which currently in newlive.myMainSite.com, you will remove park domain from oldlive.myMainSite.com and move to newlive.myMainSite.com.

then you can transfer domain smoothly.

Answer (score 0):

You can use "Redirects" option in cPanel to redirect all visitors from old to new site.
Or you can simply change Virtualhost in Apache for your main domain to directory of your finished (currently under construction site).

Answer (score 0):

Agree with the previous answer. If you would like to load the sub-domain's contents on the main site then you will need to move the data from sub-domain's directory to root directory that is public_html.

Just make sure, you do not have any live site on your main domain, If your main domain has the working site for it and you will upload the contents under the root directory then your website won't work due to conflict in contents.

If it's not possible then you will need to upload the contents under one sub-directory in public_html and after that you can access the site by yourP_website_name/directory name.

Once you will done with the moving contents then you will need to update the base UR Lto the new site URL.It is present in cPanel >> File Manager >> public_html >> Sites/Default/Settings.php